# Google App Engine custom builds (2nd generation)

Tags: google-app-engine, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

As I understand it, `gcloud app deploy` triggers a Cloud Build job behind the scenes based on command line options and things like `requirements.txt` (for python runtime). What I am looking to do is extend these Cloud Build steps to include things like database migration and testing *before* the deploy.

I can see that I could run these extra steps within separate containers in a separate GCP project, and then as the final step do something like

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: [ 'app', 'deploy', 'app.yaml', '--project', 'my-gae-project', '--version', 'staging' ]
```

Does that seem like a good way to do it? Has anyone done this kind of thing before for a GAE project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the instructions for [Building, Testing, and Deploying artifacts using Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts). There is a section under "deploying artifacts" that is specific to App Engine and how you would set up your custom build to deploy to GAE.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.